# Spring Cloud Dependencies Finchley.M9 cannot be resolved on Maven

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I am trying out new Spring Cloud project Finchley with Spring Boot 2.0.1 Release. I have created the maven project using Spring Initilizr and imported in Eclipse as Maven project. But the error I am getting in POM is -- "Could not transfer artifact o.s.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:pom: Finchley.M9". On enabling full debugging I see there is a java.net.ConnectException. Repository in the POM is :

```
<repositories>
<repository>
<id>
spring-milestone
</id>
<url>
https://repo.spring.io/milestone
</url>
<repository>
<repositories>
```

Can someone point out what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It's there, https://repo.spring.io/milestone/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-dependencies/Finchley.M9/ , maybe there was some outage. Just please try again.

Comment: This issue is persistent. Don't know why. Do I need to change something in my local Maven settings file too? I created a second project with same dependencies from Spring Initilizr and that too has the same problem. I did not tamper with default pom that I got from Spring Initilizr.

Comment: Most likely your local setup is broken. Maybe you have a `settings.xml` with some custom stuff in your local `.m2`. Maybe you have some connection issues. It doesn't seem to be a problem with repo.spring.io

Comment: The problem stays the same for me as well (while I have no custom stuff in `settings.xml`). Do you know any other resources (e.g. mirrors) where the library can be downloaded from?

Comment: No. But you should fix your setup. Generate a project from start.spring.io and copy the setup from there